pass variable number of arguments to python from shell script
I have a very simple shell script which accepts 2 arguments after some processing pass these 2 arguments to python code. like below
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
#some processing...
python3.6 abc.py $arg1 $arg2

Now the requirement is my shell script will accept variable number of arguments and it should pass same to python program. For accepting I can use
for arg in "$@" ; do
    #use array for assignments
done

but issue is how to pass it to python program.

This is not python question. No need for python tag

You don't iterate over $@ at all; you simply pass all contained arguments directly, with
python3.6 abc.py "$@"

If the arguments are, for example, 1 and 2, this results in
python3.6 abc.py "1" "2"

not
python3.6 abc.py "1 2".

This is intentionally special behavior of quoted $@, designed specifically for this purpose. If you really wanted the latter, you'd use "$*" instead.

If you need an arbitrary number of values created from the values in $@, you'll need an explicit array.
for x in "$@"; do
    # do some work on x, add the result y to the array
    arr+=("$y")
done

python3.6 abc.py "${arr[@]}"

